Error using import.meta.glob() with SvelteKit
I am trying to create this endpoint for retrieveing posts:
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'
import type { Post } from '$lib/types'

async function getPosts() {
    let posts: Post[] = []
    
    const paths = import.meta.glob('/src/posts/*.md', { eager: true })
    
    for (const path in paths) {
        const file = paths[path]
        const slug = path.split('/').at(-1)?.replace('.md', '')
    
        if (file && typeof file === 'object' && 'metadata' in file && slug) {
            const metadata = file.metadata as Omit<Post, 'slug'>
            const post = { ...metadata, slug } satisfies Post
            post.published && posts.push(post)
        }
    }
    
    posts = posts.sort((first, second) =>
        new Date(second.date).getTime() - new Date(first.date).getTime()
    )
    
    return posts
}

export async function GET() {
    const posts = await getPosts()
    return json(posts)
}

But it throws this error:
Error [RollupError]: The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
    at getRollupError (file:///C:/Users/vespe/Desktop/HATS/OI/Projects/dvemolina/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.28.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:396:41)
    at convertProgram (file:///C:/Users/vespe/Desktop/HATS/OI/Projects/dvemolina/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.28.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:1084:26)
    at parseAstAsync (file:///C:/Users/vespe/Desktop/HATS/OI/Projects/dvemolina/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.28.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:2070:106)
    at async ssrTransformScript (file:///C:/Users/vespe/Desktop/HATS/OI/Projects/dvemolina/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.11_@types+node@22.10.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CB_7IfJ-.js:52381:11)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///C:/Users/vespe/Desktop/HATS/OI/Projects/dvemolina/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.11_@types+node@22.10.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CB_7IfJ-.js:51979:72) {
  code: 'PARSE_ERROR',
  pos: 2
}

I tried everything but it doesn't work. The error seems to be when using the import.meta.glob(), because if I try some dummy it works fine.

Show your configs (Vite & Svelte) & packages (specifically the adapter being used).
